# Parse uploaded values are turning to 0 when I log out of current user and then log back in

Tags: android

This is a simple settings page for an app. When I click the applyButton, it will take the current seekerbar progress value and upload it to the cloud. It works completely fine as when I leave the settings page and then return, the values are saved. However when I log out of the current user and then log back in and go to the settings page, the value pulled from the cloud is 0 for some reason.

Near the bottom of my code I have a method called `userIsLoggedIn()`. I have log statements as follows:

```
Log.d(TAG, "got user settings from database");

Log.d(TAG, "desired work time: " + workFromDatabase);

Log.d(TAG, "desired rest time " + restFromDatabase);
```

Perhaps I'm unaware of something as my boolean value which I'm retrieving from the cloud is perfectly fine. It's only the int value that is giving me this problem.

```
public class SettingsScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String TAG = SettingsScreen.class.getSimpleName();
private static final String ACCESSEDSETTINGS = "accessed_settings";


@Bind(R.id.workText)
TextView workText;
@Bind(R.id.restText)
TextView restText;
@Bind(R.id.workSeekBar)
SeekBar workBar;
@Bind(R.id.restSeekBar)
SeekBar restBar;
@Bind(R.id.applyButton)
Button applyButton;

public static final int MAX_WORK = 60;
public static final int MIN_WORK = 5;
public static final int MAX_REST = 60;
public static final int MIN_REST = 1;
public static final String WORK = "work"; //these two will be the data uploaded to the database
public static final String REST = "rest";
public static final String LOCALWORK = "localwork"; //these two will be data sent back to main activity. only locally saved
public static final String LOCALREST = "localrest";

int workFromDatabase;
int restFromDatabase;
Boolean databaseHasValue = false;

private int mDesiredWorkTime;
private int mDesiredRestTime;

private ParseUser mUser;

Boolean isLoggedIn;

Boolean registeredUserAccessedSettings = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings_screen);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    isLoggedIn = intent.getBooleanExtra("currentUser", false);


    if (isLoggedIn) {
        userIsLoggedIn();
        Log.d(TAG, "Database has value? " + databaseHasValue);
    } else {

        workBar.setMax(MAX_WORK - MIN_WORK);
        workBar.setProgress(25 - MIN_WORK);
        workBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

                mDesiredWorkTime = MIN_WORK + progress;
                workText.setText("Current: " + mDesiredWorkTime + " minutes");

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });

        restBar.setMax(MAX_REST - MIN_REST);
        restBar.setProgress(5 - MIN_REST);
        restBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

                mDesiredRestTime = MIN_REST + progress;
                restText.setText("Current: " + mDesiredRestTime + " minutes");

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });
    }

    applyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isLoggedIn) {
                mUser.put(WORK, mDesiredWorkTime);
                mUser.put(REST, mDesiredRestTime);
                mUser.put(ACCESSEDSETTINGS, true); //when user clicks apply, ACCESSEDSETTINGS will be true and so the if statement in the method below wont run

                Log.d(TAG, "putting desired user settings into database");
                Log.d(TAG, "desired work time: " + mDesiredWorkTime);
                Log.d(TAG, "desired rest time " + mDesiredRestTime);

            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(SettingsScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(LOCALWORK, mDesiredWorkTime);
            intent.putExtra(LOCALREST, mDesiredRestTime);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}


public void userIsLoggedIn() {
    if (isLoggedIn) {
        mUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
        registeredUserAccessedSettings = mUser.getBoolean(ACCESSEDSETTINGS);

        Log.d(TAG, "Has user accessed settings before? " + registeredUserAccessedSettings);

        if (!registeredUserAccessedSettings) { //this code will run first time user accesses settings with parse

            workFromDatabase = 25;
            restFromDatabase = 5;

            Log.d(TAG, "launched settings with account for first time");

        } else {
            workFromDatabase = mUser.getInt(WORK);
            restFromDatabase = mUser.getInt(REST);

            workText.setText("Current: " + workFromDatabase + " minutes");
            restText.setText("Current: " + restFromDatabase + " minutes");

            databaseHasValue = true;

            Log.d(TAG, "got user settings from database");
            Log.d(TAG, "desired work time: " + workFromDatabase);
            Log.d(TAG, "desired rest time " + restFromDatabase);
        }


        workBar.setMax(MAX_WORK - MIN_WORK);
        workBar.setProgress(workFromDatabase - MIN_WORK);

        workBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

                mDesiredWorkTime = MIN_WORK + progress;
                workText.setText("Current: " + mDesiredWorkTime + " minutes");
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });


        restBar.setMax(MAX_REST - MIN_REST);
        restBar.setProgress(restFromDatabase - MIN_REST);

        restBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

                mDesiredRestTime = MIN_REST + progress;
                restText.setText("Current: " + mDesiredRestTime + " minutes");

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });


    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is really simple. You're not "*uploading it to the cloud*", you're just setting those values on your **local** `ParseUser` object.

For example:

```
mUser.put(WORK, mDesiredWorkTime);
```

is **NOT** saving anything to the remote database. It's just setting the field indicated by the `WORK` key with the value stored in `mDesiredWorkTime` in your **local** `ParseUser` object.

To fix your issue change this:

```
mUser.put(WORK, mDesiredWorkTime);
mUser.put(REST, mDesiredRestTime);
mUser.put(ACCESSEDSETTINGS, true);
```

to this:

```
mUser.put(WORK, mDesiredWorkTime);
mUser.put(REST, mDesiredRestTime);
mUser.put(ACCESSEDSETTINGS, true);
mUser.saveInBackground(); // <----------------------- THIS SAVES YOUR USER TO THE DATABASE
```

(instead of [`saveInBackground()`](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseObject.html#saveInBackground()) you can also use [`saveInBackground(SaveCallback callback)`](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseObject.html#saveInBackground(com.parse.SaveCallback)) or [`save()`](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseObject.html#save()), depending on your actual needs...)

Comment: Oh how stupid of me! I completely forgot that I needed to use saveInBackground(). Thank you very much :)